# Test every time is skipped by PHPUnit

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I'm using PHPUnit with CakePHP to test a **Custom Finder** but test is every time skipped and I do not know what the reason

> OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!

TestCase:

```
class UsersTableTest extends TestCase
{ 

public $fixtures = [
'app.users',
        'app.user_types',
        'app.bookings',
        'app.stores'
    ];

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->Users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
    }

public function testFindUser(){
    $query = $this->Users->find('user', [
        'fields' => ['Users.id', 'Users.email', 'Users.password',
            'Users.username'],
        'conditions' => ['Users.id' => 900000]
    ]);
    $this->assertInstanceOf('Cake\ORM\Query', $query);
    $result = $query->hydrate(false)->toArray();

    $expected = [
        [
            'id' => 900000,
            'email' => 'usuariocomum1@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'usuariocomum1senha',
            'username' => 'usuariocomum1username'
        ]
    ];

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
}
```

Method tested:

```
public function findUser(Query $query, array $options){
    $query->where($options);
    return $query;
}
```

Users Fixture:

```
public $records = [
    [
        'id' => 900000,
        'email' => 'usuariocomum1@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'usuariocomum1senha',
        'username' => 'usuariocomum1username',
        'user_type_id' => 900000,
        'created' => '2015-07-17 18:46:47',
        'modified' => '2015-07-17 18:46:47'
    ]
]
```

I'm Following this tutorial [CakePHP 3.0 Testing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-table-classes)

**[EDIT 1]**

With --verbose flag:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping>vendor\bin\phpunit --verbose tests\TestCase\Mo
del\Table\UsersTableTest
PHPUnit 4.8.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:        PHP 5.6.3
Configuration:  C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\phpunit.xml.dist

III.

Time: 15.87 seconds, Memory: 7.50Mb

There were 3 incomplete tests:

1) App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest::testInitialize
Not implemented yet.

C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\tests\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest.php:
58

2) App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest::testValidationDefault
Not implemented yet.

C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\tests\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest.php:
71

3) App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest::testBuildRules
Not implemented yet.

C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\tests\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest.php:
81

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 4, Assertions: 2, Incomplete: 3.
```

**[EDIT 2]**

When I change test to:

```
public function testFindUser(){
    $query = $this->Users->find('user', [
        'fields' => ['Users.id', 'Users.email', 'Users.password',
            'Users.username', 'Users.user_type_id', 'Users.created',
            'Users.modified'],
        'conditions' => ['Users.id' => 900000]
    ]);
    $this->assertInstanceOf('Cake\ORM\Query', $query);
    $result = $query->hydrate(false)->toArray();

    $expected = [
        [
            'id' => 900000,
            'email' => 'usuariocomum1@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'usuariocomum1senha',
            'username' => 'usuariocomum1username',
            'user_type_id' => 900000,
            'created' => '2015-07-17 18:46:47',
            'modified' => '2015-07-17 18:46:47'

        ]
    ];

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
}
```

the test is executed but fails (`hidrate(false)` could make created and modified primitive objects)(Why now works? why `'user_type_id' => 900000` displayed)

my console:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping>vendor\bin\phpunit tests\TestCase\Model\Table\
UsersTableTest
PHPUnit 4.8.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

IIIF

Time: 8.13 seconds, Memory: 7.75Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) App\Test\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest::testFindUser
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
         'user_type_id' => 900000
-        'created' => '2015-07-17 18:46:47'
-        'modified' => '2015-07-17 18:46:47'
+        'created' => Cake\I18n\Time Object (...)
+        'modified' => Cake\I18n\Time Object (...)
     )
 )

C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\tests\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest.php:
107

FAILURES!
Tests: 4, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1, Incomplete: 3.
```

**[EDIT 3]**

I clean my TestCase and delete all not implemented test (created by bake) and this is the output:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping>vendor\bin\phpunit tests\TestCase\Model\Table\
UsersTableTest
PHPUnit 4.8.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.

Time: 6.06 seconds, Memory: 7.50Mb

OK (1 test, 2 assertions)
**NOTE** CakePHP 3.0.11 PHPUnit 4.8.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this in your other question, hadn't we? The `testFindUser` test is *not* being skipped, it runs just fine as you can tell from the PHPUnit output, and from the fact that you receive a failure message when you change your code so that it produces and error, if it were skipped, there would have been no failures, and the output would have been `IIIS`.

> **OK**, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
>   Tests: **4**, Assertions: 2, Incomplete: **3**.

*<sup>* emphasis mine</sup>*

4 tests in total, 3 incomplete, = 1 test ran

The message just says that there are incomplete/non-implemented tests, **additionally** to the tests that ran `OK`.

The verbose level output makes this even more clear, in showing you exactly which tests are incomplete - none of them is your `testFindUser` test.

You may want to have a closer look at the docs, to get a grasp on how to interpret the output.

**https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html**

Comment: OK I remove all not implemented tests (created by bake) and put the result in edit 3 on my question, can you see?

Comment: @ricardo Yes, I can see it, it's the expected output, it shows that 1 test with 2 assertions ran successfully.

Comment: @ndn you can explain how I test in [EDIT 2]? because I expect a String but I receive an object

Comment: @ricardo Hydration is the process of transforming data into entity object structures, the data type of the values is not being affected, ie time based columns will always be transformed into time class instances (unless you'd override the [**default type mapping**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#data-types)), integers stay integers, etc... Creating time instances in your comparison data set like `'created' =>  new \Cake\I18n\Time('2015-07-17 18:46:47')` should work fine.